# List of ints to string - haskell?

Tags: haskell, dictionary, repeat

I am trying to take a list of integers and repeat them a number of times, but as a string in haskell. The expected output is:

```
> nnn [3,1,5] = ["3-3-3","1","5-5-5-5-5"]
> nnn [10,2,4] = ["10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10","2-2","4-4-4-4"]
```

Now I think I am close... But I can't quite turn a list of ints into a String, and definitely don't know what to do about the hyphen. Here's my code so far, and output:

```
nnn :: [Int] -> [[Char]]
nnn list = map show (map (\x -> take x $ repeat x) list)
```

And it gives me:

```
> nnn [3,1,5] = ["[3,3,3]","[1]","[5,5,5,5,5]"]
```

(I'm close at least!) Can anyone point me in the right direction to look here? :)

Comment: `map show` first. Search [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=a+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D) for a function that puts values between other ones using the type `a -> [a] -> [a]` and you find `intersperse`: "The intersperse function takes an element and a list and intersperses that element between the elements of the list. For example,  `intersperse ',' "abcde" == "a,b,c,d,e"`". `concat` when you're done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A *separate* function to repeat a number into a hyphen-separated string seems useful here. Convert the number to a string first, replicate it, and use `intercalate` to insert a hyphen between each element and join them:

```
repeatNumber :: Int -> String
repeatNumber n = intercalate "-" $ replicate n $ show n
```

Then `nnn` is nice and simple:

```
nnn :: [Int] -> [String]
nnn = map repeatNumber
```

(`replicate a b` being `take a $ repeat b`)

Comment: "intercalate" is not in the prelude, is it? So I would have to import Data.List?

Comment: Is there a similar prelude function I can use, or would that change everything? Haha

Comment: @user3290526: No, there isn’t (that’s why it exists in Data.List), but why wouldn’t you want to use it? I suppose you could always define `intercalate _ x@[_] = x; intercalate s (x:xs) = x:s:intercalate s xs` yourself.